# Passing conditional where clause through string parameter? (asp.net/c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, conditional-statements, checkboxlist

```
foreach (ListItem lst in chkPrice.Items)
{
    if (lst.Selected)
    {
        if (lst.Value == "1")
        {
            P = ">=1 AND <=2000";
        }
        if (lst.Value == "2")
        {
            P = "BETWEEN 2000 AND 5000";
        }
        if (lst.Value == "3")
        {
            P = "BETWEEN 5000 AND 8000";
        }
        if (lst.Value == "4")
        {
            P = "Greater Than 8000";
        }

        P = P + "," + P;
        PS = true;
    }


Query = "Select * from tbl_Product WHERE Product_SalePrice IN (" + P + ") ";
ViewProductCode(Query);


<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkPrice" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;PKR 0 - PKR 2000" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;PKR 2000 - PKR 5000" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>`enter code here`
    <asp:ListItem Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;PKR 5000 - PKR 8000" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;PKR 8000 and above" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

How condition should be written in p string parameter to pass it ti the Query?

Comment: Sorry, but the question is not clear to me. Please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how-to-create-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you to ask a good question.

Comment: i just want to know how the condition of the WHERE clause should be written in P (that is a string variable) and passed in this query.                                                 Query = "Select * from tbl_Product WHERE Product_SalePrice IN (" + P + ") ";

Answer (score 0):

In checkbox, only the selected items are passed on. So you don't need to check for the `list.selected`. And instead of using all these `if` statements use `switch`

```
p = '';
foreach (ListItem lst in chkPrice.Items) {
    switch(lst.Value) {
        case "1":
            P += " BETWEEN 1 AND 2000";
            break;
        case "2":
            P += " BETWEEN 2000 AND 5000";
            break;
        case "3":
            P += " BETWEEN 5000 AND 8000";
            break;
        case "4":
            P += " > 8000";
            break;
        default:
            // define a default behavious
            break;
    }
    if(lst.key != lst.length-1) {
        P += "OR Product_SalePrice"
    }
    PS = true;
}


Query = "Select * from tbl_Product WHERE Product_SalePrice " + P;
ViewProductCode(Query);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! But I'm still getting error in query syntax. It calls incorrect syntax to both written in case 1 and case 2,3 for case 4 it says "incorrect syntax near than".

Comment: What did you do? You made it work with `IN`? Or did you use `OR` in the query?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I used OR and made some modifications.I posted it above.It may not be a good way but it worked.Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried the same thing and was about to edit my answer. Then you said you got it working. I edited my answer anyway. Good luck with your project. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach (ListItem lst in chkPrice.Items)
            {
                if (lst.Selected)
                {
                    if (I > 0)

                    {
                        P = P + " OR Product_SalePrice";
                    }
                    switch (lst.Value)
                    {
                        case "1":
                            P += " BETWEEN 1 AND 2000";
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            P += " BETWEEN 2000 AND 5000 ";
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            P += " BETWEEN 5000 AND 8000";
                            break;
                        case "4":
                            P += " >= 8000";
                            break;

                    }
                    I++;
                    PS = true;
                }
            }
```

Query = "Select * from tbl_Product WHERE Product_SalePrice " + P + " ";
ViewProductCode(Query);